# Is there a way to get a "window opening" animation time in Windows

Tags: winapi, windows-10

Is there a way (for instance a Win32 API function) to get the time of a windows animation (i.e. when the window is opened from the minimized state from the task bar)?

When desktop effects are turned off, the animation time is equal to 0, however when the desktop effects are enabled (Windows 7 Aero or Windows 10 desktop effects), there is an animation which takes some time.

The problem is that if we call `IsVisible()` for a window that is still animating after clicking on it in a task bar, the function returns `TRUE`, despite the fact that the window is not fully visible (until the animation is finished).

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between "window is visible" and "window has finished animating"?

Comment: @andlabs, I grab a window from the screen DC and I have to ensure that I capture only that window (the FPS is ~15).

Comment: Or, if not possible, it would be interesting to know if the window is still "animating" at a given moment, it would solve my problem.